# org.jruby.Main intercepts Cntrl+C

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

```
org.jruby.Main main = new org.jruby.Main()
main.run(new String[] {"blah", "blah"})
```

For whatever reason, running JRuby in this fashion, or in a thread with this invocation, <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> won't kill the calling process (in my case Tomcat).

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Was tagged with Grails, Tomcat and Groovy, but asks about a JRuby specific topic.

Comment: Works for me.  What version of JRuby?

Comment: 1.6.1 and 1.6.2. Note that the program in question is doing something to watch for Cntrl+C, as the prompt of the gem explicitly says "Cntrl+C" to quit. I may have to investigate the source and figure out what exactly this specific ruby application is doing.